# Drawing on data from combobox MFC vc++ 2008

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I need to plot points on an MFC dialog box. But it has to be such that the selection of which points is the users choice. 
For eg, I have 3 arrays A,B,C and the combo box has 3 options
When I choose A, the program should plot points from array A on the bitmap.So far I've been using DCPaint to draw all the points from all 3 arrays simultaneously. How I draw them one by one?

Comment: What is DCPaint? Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Please specify what you are asking for. The details seam to simple for me. When you have a combo box, you get a notification (WM_COMMAND) when the selection changes. When you know what is selected, you should know what you print... or display. Having a separate control gives you the chance to pass the information of what is selected to it....

Comment: I've used the usual MoveTo and LineTo along withsetpixel to plot a line graph before. This I had done within the OnInitDialog. 
I could plot all the points together, ie all points from all 3 arrays.
What I need is for the bitmap to be redrawn with data from one array each time i choose something from the combobox

Comment: Also, I figured out how to read the text from a combobox, and I have a function ready to return values of array A, when string "A" is returned from the comboBox control